How to create projectiles in shared mode in Photon Fusion 2
I am developing a multiplayer game in Unity by following the Fusion 2 Shared mode tutorial
I'm going to make an online 2D game and I looked up how to make projectiles to make bullets, and found the "Projectile Essentials" sample. The methods used in this tutorial seem to work in Host mode, but not in Shared mode, so I think I might have to create the implementation for the projectiles myself.
I'd prefer if there was a tutorial for making projectiles in shared mode, but if I had to make it myself how would I do it to reduce the load and make it work quickly?
I think I can save all the bullets at once as a variable and make them [Networked], but I can't easily think of a way to load and optimize only what I need in the player environment. The projectile may appear to move in a stutter depending on the tick rate.

Most of the principles established in the host-mode projectiles sample carries over into shared mode, you just need to worry about each client instantiating / being the state authority. As for a tutorial / sample / implementation of this, the Fusion 2 Tanknarock Sample supports both Host mode and Shared mode.
For example, Tanknarock uses the Example 5 - Projectile Data Buffer - Kinematic technique from the projectile essentials sample, where the data for each projectile is stored inside a Weapon class (Assets/Scripts/Tanknarok/Player/Weapon.cs), instead of instantiating new NetworkObjects for the projectiles from prefabs. It's done this way to reduce the visual lag that comes with spawning new objects.
// Tanknarock's Weapon.cs class...

[Networked] public override ref NetworkState State => ref MakeRef<NetworkState>();
public struct NetworkState : INetworkStruct
{
    [Networked, Capacity(12)] 
    public NetworkArray<ShotState> bulletStates => default;
}

public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
{
    bullets.Process( this, (ref ShotState bullet, int tick) =>
    {
        ...
    }
}

public override void Render()
{
    if (TryGetStateChanges(out var from, out var to))
        OnFireTickChanged();
    else
        TryGetStateSnapshots(out from, out _, out _, out _, out _);

    bullets.Render(this, from.bulletStates );
}

All projectiles are handled in that bullets.Process delegate / loop inside of FixedUpdateNetwork, and the visuals are handled in the Render function, moving local-only gameObjects to make it seem like the projectile prefabs themselves are networked.
Notice how the bulletStates array has a max capacity of 12: Capacity(12), meaning that at most, each weapon can have 12 projectiles at once. If you needed more, you can just bump up that number to however many you need (up to the max size allowed for a single NetworkObject)
